# how to assign value to bootstrap input='date'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, input

I want assign to input=date a value extract from database,
the html is

`<input type="date" class="form-control" name="endDate" id='endDate'>`,

the assign javascript is `$('#endDate').attr('value','2015-02-02');`,

but this cannot work, unless I assign it manually like:

`<input type="date" class="form-control" name="endDate" id='endDate' value='2015-02-02'>`
Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/jd3AK/

Comment: With jQuery, you can also use `$('#endDate').val('2015-02-02')`

Comment: Check your `input#ids`, do you assign them multiple times?